# Noticing a lot of "views" lately, badges which probably aren't deserved

Tags: support, badges

I have been noticing that a few of my questions are getting a lot of views in a very short period of time.

I don't know that it's always exactly this scenario, but I'm getting Notable Question and Popular Question badges on the same day for the same question.  This basic idea has happened with a few questions lately on different sites.

I don't think the questions are so particularly awesome or just suddenly applicable.  I more suspect either a change in the site's code on how it counts views or a flood of automated views.

Just calling somebody's attention to it.  Anyone else noticing the same thing lately?

Comment: I'm sure posting this question would attract further views :)

Comment: We're watching you....we're all watching you.

Comment: @Bart I told you they'd post it here...

Comment: I think it must be NSA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely someone linked to your question from somewhere very busy lately; perhaps someone posted on a forum or another Q/A site about the same issue, and someone linked to your question as related.

There haven't been any changes in the site itself which would have affected this.

Comment: [Obligatory link to your recent question earning "Popular Question", for the sake of irony ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715961/grammar-spec-resolving-shift-reduce-conflicts)